# What's the timeline of Motorola 6800-family CPUs from 1974 to 1979?

Tags: 6800

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800), The Motorola 6800 was released in 1974. Between that and the release of the 6809 in 1979 (or 1978?) there was at least one other 6800-series CPU released, the 6802 microcontroller with the same registers and instruction set as the 6800. The 6801/6803 microcontrollers, which added some additional instructions, were apparently released in 1978 or 1979, but I don't know if this was before or after the 6809.

I'd like a list of all 6800-like processors and microcontrollers released by Motorola up to the time the 6809 became available for purchase in non-sample quantities, along with notes on programming model changes (such as additional instructions or registers). I don't need details about changes, on-chip or not, that are not directly part of the CPU, such as on-board memory or I/O.

I'm mainly interested in availability dates, by which I mean the date any random person or company could walk in off the street and buy them in quantities of a thousand or more. But feel free to provide announcement dates, too, so long as the announcement covers the final details of the processor programming model.

Comment: These definitions are rather unclear, as 'Release Dates' are usually a marketing tool. Availability can be before and after (usually after), also the 'I' in "when could I actually buy one" covers quite a range, as new devices are usually offered at different times first to different channels.

Comment: Good point. I've tried to clarify this in the question; let me know if it's more clear now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Figure 1-1 (page 1-4) in [[mot81](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladaMicroprocessorsDataManual_80083566)] gives an overview of the early days
of the 6800 family:

[image: Genealogy of the cohesive M6800 microprocessor/microcomputer family]

This can't be read for exact dates so I've included everything that is
not clearly after the 6809 and added further details from other
sources documented below.

```
Production  Annnounced      Product
1974-11     1974-03         6800 microprocessor
1976-07?    ?               68A00, 68B00 (1.5 and 2 MHz)
            1977-03         6802, 6808 (onboard clock+RAM, clock)
            1978-08         6801, 6803
1979?       1978-07?        6809, 68HC09
            1979?           6805
            1979-12         68HC05
```

- **6800**: "[A]nnounced in March 1974 and was in full production by
  the end of that year." "The M6800 microcomputer system was finally
  in production by November 1974." Sourced in [[wp6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800)].
- **68A00**, **68B00**: "The new parts were available in July 1976."
  Sourced in [[wp6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800)].
- **6802**, **6808**: Added onboard clock and (6802 only) 128 bytes of
  RAM. Announced by March 3rd 1977. Sourced in [[wp6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800)].
- **6801**, **6803**: Adds 16-bit "D" register as concatenation of A
  and B and various new instructions, including multiply. Slightly to
  the left of 1979 in the [[mot81](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladaMicroprocessorsDataManual_80083566)] diagram, though data sheets for it
  don't appear until [[mot83mpu](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/19838BitMicroprocessorandPeripheralData.2109768863/view)]. [[wp6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800)] references "*Product
  Preview MC6801*, Austin, Texas: Motorola Semiconductor Products.
  August 1978. NP-93." This or a very similar MCU appears to have been
  in use by General Motors as early as 1977[[shack](http://www.cpushack.com/2016/08/19/cpu-of-the-day-motorola-mc6801-the-second-first-6800-mcu/)]; it's referred to
  in [[oral](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102702020)] as a "GMCM" and in [[mot88v1](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladacessorMicrocontrollerandPeripheralDataVo_47516431/page/n13)] Figure 1-1 (p. 1-3) as
  "custom CPU."
- **6809**: The earliest mention I can find that includes a month is
  in an Elsevier journal.[[elsev]] This seems unlikely to be the
  initial announcement, but is probably well before production. (6809s
  were not on sale in the back pages of *Byte* in December 1977.)
- **6805**: Optimized for controller applications; incompatible
  architectural changes such as X register reduced to 8 bits. It may
  have existed internally at Motorla as early as 1977 or 1978: "this
  is '77-'78 timeframe -- they came and said, 'Hey, we'd like to have
  a CMOS version of this 6805 variant."[[oral](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102702020)]. (The M14605 is the
  CMOS 6805. It and several 6805 variants have data sheets in
  [[mot81](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladaMicroprocessorsDataManual_80083566)].) [[shack](http://www.cpushack.com/2016/08/19/cpu-of-the-day-motorola-mc6801-the-second-first-6800-mcu/)] claims release in 1979. `archive.org` has an
  *M6805 M14605 Family Users Manual* dated 1980.
- **68HC05**: "A low-power variation of the 05," "shipped..in December
  of 1979."[[oral](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102702020)]

In case you're wondering about the "holes" in this numbering scheme:
The **6804** was a reduced cost modification of the 6805 released
around 1982. The **6806** and **6807** designations were never used,
as far as I can tell. The **6810** was a RAM chip. The **6811** was a
6801 extension introduced in 1984. The **6812** in turn extended that,
but not until the 1990s. From the beginning parts from **6820**
onwards were peripherals.

**References**

- [elsev] "MC6809 microprocessor", Microprocessors, Elsevier, vol 2
  issue 3 p. 162. July 1978.
- [mot81] [*Motorola Microprocessors Data Manual*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladaMicroprocessorsDataManual_80083566). 1981.
- [mot83mpu] [*8-Bit Microprocessor & Peripheral Data*](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/19838BitMicroprocessorandPeripheralData.2109768863/view).
  Motorola, 1983.
- [mot83mcu] [*Single-chip Microcomputer Data*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladaipMicrocontrollerData_42672102). Motorola,
  1983.
- [mot88v1] [*Microprocessor, Microcontroller and Peripheral Data,
  Volume I*](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_motoroladacessorMicrocontrollerandPeripheralDataVo_47516431/page/n13). Motorola, 1988.
- [oral] [*Motorola 6800 oral history panel: development and
  promotion*](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102702020). Computer History Museum, 2008.
- [shack] [CPU of the Day: Motorola MC6801 – The (second) first
  6800 MCU](http://www.cpushack.com/2016/08/19/cpu-of-the-day-motorola-mc6801-the-second-first-6800-mcu/). www.cpushack.com, 2016.
- [wp6800] [Motorola 6800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6800). Wikipedia.